# Trim search results based on user permissions

Tags: development, web-part, search, security-trimming

Is it possible to create web part with Sharepoint APIs that will trim search results like [this](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/veselin-vasilev-blog/2013/03/18/trim-the-search-results-based-on-permissions-roles). I would need similar thing to check does user have edit permission on documents retreived from search results.

I guess other option would be developing post trimmer (ISecurityTrimmerPost)?

Comment: E.g. by using SharePoint's REST API the returns based on your query are automatically security trimmed. You mention using a web part, and e.g. the Content Query Web Part does this too automatically as it's based on the built-in search. Not too sure what kind of web part you are after.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that results are security trimmed but I need from search to return only documents with edit permissions. I've tried crawling "shared with" but it doesn't contain all users because inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make console app with CSOM to get permissions for documents with code blow but to check permissions I need full rights or I get access denied. I will need to move this code to web part and check permissions with elevated rights.

```
public static void Search()
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://server.company.com"))
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = ".docx";
            // Title,SiteName,SiteId,WebId,Path,contentclass,isdocument
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SPSiteUrl");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SiteName");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("SiteId");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("WebId");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Path");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("contentclass");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("isdocument");
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);

            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", resultRow["Title"], resultRow["Path"]);
                    Web web = clientContext.Site.OpenWebById(new Guid(resultRow["WebId"].ToString()));

                    clientContext.Load(web);
                    clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    if (web != null)
                    {
                        var url = web.Url;
                        var relurl = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        File f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl((relurl.Length > 1 ? relurl : "") + resultRow["Path"].ToString().Remove(0, url.Length));
                        clientContext.Load(f);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        if (f != null)
                        {
                            ListItem item = f.ListItemAllFields;
                            var permissions = item.GetUserEffectivePermissions(web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                            foreach (var permission in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PermissionKind)).Cast<PermissionKind>())
                            {
                                var permissionName = Enum.GetName(typeof(PermissionKind), permission);
                                var hasPermission = permissions.Value.Has(permission);
                                Console.WriteLine("Permission: {0}, HasPermission: {1}", permissionName, hasPermission);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Search or the query API. A user just needs view rights to an item in SharePoint for the results to show. You would need to develop a solution (probably using an elevated account) to enumerate the items and determine if the current user has Edit rights.

Comment: Thanks. Link that I've added to post tells me it is achivable. I've played with CSOM SearchExecutor and I get Search results that contain document urls and bunch of other properties (similar properties are returnd by Search results web part). Now I need to get SPListItem from document url. I will try this with SP API not CSOM.

Comment: I edited my post, would it be possible to check user permission level in ISecurityTrimmerPost ?

Comment: Sure, if you have the option to write a custom security trimmer. You cannot do this in SPO only SharePoint on-prem.